# Ubuntu 16.04 takes excessive Boot Time

Tags: boot, 16.04

Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit is taking excessive Boot Time i.e. 30 sec.

I used `systemd-analyze` command in Terminal and this is the result:

```
Startup finished in 9.000s (kernel) + 21.111s (userspace) = 30.111s
```

Then, I used `systemd-analyze blame` and this is the result:

```
  7.706s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
  4.605s dev-sda1.device
  4.280s apparmor.service
  3.741s accounts-daemon.service
  3.347s NetworkManager.service
  3.338s cmdavd.service
  2.462s gpu-manager.service
  2.443s console-setup.service
  2.059s thermald.service
  2.055s cmdmgd.service
  1.765s grub-common.service
  1.541s systemd-cryptsetup@cryptswap1.service
  1.455s apport.service
  1.393s snap-ubuntu\x2dcore-109.mount
  1.309s ondemand.service
  1.196s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
  1.167s bluetooth.service
  1.073s lightdm.service
   835ms lm-sensors.service
   828ms rsyslog.service
   822ms irqbalance.service
   820ms avahi-daemon.service
   808ms upower.service
   807ms binfmt-support.service
   670ms systemd-journald.service
   635ms polkitd.service
   627ms snap-telegram\x2dsergiusens-3.mount
   608ms systemd-modules-load.service
   604ms colord.service
   554ms systemd-udevd.service
   518ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
   490ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
   457ms systemd-rfkill.service
   443ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
   427ms systemd-journal-flush.service
   401ms kmod-static-nodes.service
   393ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
   381ms systemd-update-utmp.service
   370ms dev-mqueue.mount
   357ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
   336ms systemd-localed.service
   329ms systemd-logind.service
   325ms systemd-hostnamed.service...skipping...
   134ms speech-dispatcher.service
   115ms alsa-restore.service
   113ms dns-clean.service
   103ms ufw.service
   100ms systemd-user-sessions.service
    98ms pppd-dns.service
    90ms dev-hugepages.mount
    72ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
    61ms snapd.socket
    58ms dev-mapper-cryptswap1.swap
    51ms resolvconf.service
    49ms rtkit-daemon.service
    46ms user@1001.service
    29ms rc-local.service
    22ms systemd-remount-fs.service
    22ms hddtemp.service
    16ms plymouth-start.service
    14ms tmp.mount
    11ms plymouth-read-write.service
     5ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
     2ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
     2ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
     1ms dev-loop0.device
```

Using Dell 5521 Laptop with following specs:

**Processor:** Intel® Core™ i5-3337U CPU @ 1.80GHz × 4

**Graphics:** Intel® Ivybridge Mobile

**Memory:** 3.7 GiB

**Swap:** 3.8 GB

**How to minimize the current Boot Time?**

Comment: Is your boot drive an SSD? If not, 30 secs is a pretty good time.

Comment: 30 seconds isn't excessive at all. I have Ubuntu on an HDD and it takes about that or even longer to be fully ready for use. If you have an SSD, then things could be different.

Comment: I am comparing this Ubuntu with its previous releases. The Ubuntu which used to take around 8 seconds is taking much more time.

Comment: Using HDD. How much  boot time is taken on SSD normally?

Answer (score 1):

30 secs sounds good if you don't have SSD (mine is 48sec) . Try disabling some applications from the Startup Applications program. Also take a look at these services:

- Disable bluetooth.service if you don't use bluetooth by executing `systemctl disable bluetooth` and you will gain about 1 sec.
- The  `cmdavd.service` and `cmdmgd.service` must be from the comodo antivirus (and I guess you want it running), if not then remove it and you will gain about 5.5 secs.
- The `apparmor.service` takes a bit much time (mine takes about 500 ms) but I guess you shouldn't disable it for security reasons  and I didn't find any more information on the internet of how to make it faster. You can run `systemctl status apparmor` and `journalctl |grep apparmor` commands to see some info but I don't think you will understand any of it, at least I don't :P

All else seem normal.