# Long firmware boot time Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: firmware

My firmware takes a very long time to boot. Running systemd-analyze gives

```
Startup finished in 25.778s (firmware) + 4.166s (loader) + 3.412s (kernel) + 1.223s (userspace) = 34.581s
```

Is there any way I can reduce this?

My specs are **i7 6700HQ**, **8GB RAM**, **256GB SSD** and **Nvidia GTX 960M**.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/790902/ubuntu-16-04-takes-excessive-boot-time

Comment: The firmware is your mainboard's BIOS/UEFI system, not Ubuntu. It runs before Ubuntu or its GRUB boot loader even get started, so Ubuntu can not be responsible or affect that time. Check your BIOS/UEFI settings, maybe there's a "Skip POST" or "Fast Boot" option or it waits to discover some disks or USB devices.

Comment: How is that related? userspace/kernel boot time is not the issue here.

Comment: @ByteCommander I have enabled fast boot and it isn't waiting to discover any disks or devices. The laptop came pre-installed with Win10 and it booted in 10 seconds max, but ever since I installed Ubuntu the boot time has been noticeably slow.

Comment: Possibly it doesn't like the way Ubuntu's boot loader EFI file is configured/registered/whatever. I don't know much about that or how to fix it though, if it should be the case.

Answer (score 1):

By disabling Legacy USB 3.0. in BIOS I reduced the firmware boot time from **25.778s** to **8.214s**; does anyone know why this would be?