# Ubuntu boot time: long firmware and loader time

Tags: 20.04, boot-time

I installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on [Dell Precision Tower 7910](https://objects.icecat.biz/objects/mmo_29764978_1479923010_8144_27320.pdf). The boot time is very long for some reason.

```
(base) hell@Dell-Precision-T7910:~$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 46.025s (firmware) + 27.522s (loader) + 10.865s (kernel) + 12.377s (userspace) = 1min 36.790s 
graphical.target reached after 12.366s in userspace
```

Here I assume that ([from this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/869901/1230667)) Ubuntu can't really do anything with firmware time as the BIOS is responsible for firmware loading time. Also, I don't want to disable any device.

[Here is the output](https://github.com/praksharma/temp/blob/f4d620c6ac6376399ddfe112475abaccd3113880/ABC/text.txt) of `sudo journalctl -b`. Is it safe to share this output here?

I do not understand where the problem is.

UPDATE: Adding more details

```
(base) hell@Dell-Precision-T7910:~$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb2 during installation
UUID=e5fbfc2f-b5d3-412b-97bb-1061c9616087 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=9BA7-EAD1  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
(base) hell@Dell-Precision-T7910:~$ lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,uuid
NAME   FSTYPE   SIZE FSUSED LABEL PARTLABEL            MOUNTPOINT UUID
sda           931.5G                                              
├─sda1 vfat     512M   5.2M       EFI System Partition /boot/efi  9BA7-EAD1
└─sda2 ext4     931G  29.5G                            /          e5fbfc2f-b5d3-412b-97bb-1061c9616087
sr0            1024M                                              
(base) hell@Dell-Precision-T7910:~$
```

Comment: are you booting from HDD or SSD?

Comment: If an update, check  UUIDs of every partition in fstab with actual UUIDs of your partitions. `cat /etc/fstab` & `lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,uuid`

Comment: @Esther I am booting from SSD. its samsung 870 qvo 1tb.

Comment: @oldfred I have added the outputs of the commands you requested.

Comment: I would make sure both UEFI & SSD firmware are latest versions. Drives all look correct. You only have ESP & / partitions with matching UUIDs. That install drive changed from sdb to sda should not matter as you use UUID, not device like sda. Some other settings to review. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster

Comment: Yes I updated the BIOS and SSD firmware from a previous installation of Windows 10 on the same PC.